# AJAX Long Polling Not Working

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, polling

I recently upgraded my XAMPP from 1.8.1 to 1.8.3 which included upgrading php from 5.4 to 5.5, and mySQL from 5.5 to 5.6.

After upgrading, my ajax polling script is not working my code goes as follows:

```
  //define setInterval in global variable, to be cleared later      

  myInterval = setInterval(function(){ 

     //this alert works
     alert('inside interval');
     $.ajax({
           url: "../php/pollScript.php",
           dataType: "json",
           data: {action: 'get_count' },
           success: function(data){
               //never reaches this function, alert is not seen
               alert('success');
           },
           error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
               alert(xhr.status);
               alert(thrownError);
           }
     )};
  }, 2000);

 //use jquery ajax form to submit form that invokes long running php script
 $("form").submit();

 //interval is cleared in success function of ajax form submit
```

So clearly, the setInterval function is working, but the ajax function is not being executed, I made sure to use **session_write_close()**; in the long running script to release the session, no code was changed before the update. Any ideas to what is going on? Is there a config I need to change in the **php.ini** to allow for polling?

**UPDATE:** after adding the error handler Im getting error status of 0, cant think of why this would happen since I havent changed any code, Ive read that this can be a result of your ajax request being canceled before completion....And there is NO hit on the server for the pollingScript.php in the chrome dev tools->Networking Tab

Long running script works perfectly too.

Comment: did you check if there's even a hit on your server for that particular pollScript.php file? did you put in an `error:` handler in the ajax call to take care of if/when something does blow up? Perhaps the ajax call is failing, but since there's no error handler, you never see output because execution just drops off the end of the script.

Comment: @MarcB added the error handler and Im getting error status of 0, what could be causing this?

Answer (score 0):

I wish I could post this clearly in a comment but here it goes.

I highly recommend using `console.log()` instead of `alert()` because it is infinitely more useful like this:

```
//define setInterval in global variable, to be cleared later      

myInterval = setInterval(function(){ 

 //this alert works
 alert('inside interval');
 $.ajax({
       url: "../php/pollScript.php",
       dataType: "json",
       data: {action: 'get_count' },
       success: function(data){
           //never reaches this function, alert is not seen
           console.log(data);
       },
       error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
           console.log(xhr.status);
           console.log(thrownError);
       }
  )};
}, 2000);

//use jquery ajax form to submit form that invokes long running php script
$("form").submit();

//interval is cleared in success function of ajax form submit
```

Also, become best friends with your Network tab no matter what browser you use. It is recommended to have this tab open when refreshing your page.

Find `pollScript.php` in your network tab when you refresh the page and simply click on it.

Good luck!